# FLIR thermal camera with Slam_gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, erratic-gazebo, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

i am using ubuntu 10.04 with diamondback. currently i have erratic robot in some test environment in Gazebo. i am taking Laser scan and generating map by Gmapping package. what i want is to put thermal camera on that erratic robot and take some color information too which could also be visible on that map.

Any clues how to do it?
(P.S bear with me i am a newbie of ROS)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27968/flir-thermal-camera-with-slam_gmapping/) by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on ROS Answers with karma: 235 on 2012-02-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The map generated by gmapping is an occupancy grid map, with the grey scale color information being a a representation of the probability of occupancy of each grid cell. For this reason "drawing into the map" is not a intended use case from a SLAM system perspective.

A practical variant for visualization is probably using the [Marker](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/Marker) system for rviz. Using markers, you can leave the map unchanged and additionally publish information about detected objects. If you want to publish a dense thermal map of high resolution (with thousands of markers), this might choke up wireless connectivity/rendering etc. however.

If you really want to draw into the map:
What you can do is listening to the map on the "/map" topic or retrieving it via the "/map" service. Once you have retrieved a copy, you can do whatever you want with the data. You can for example write the map data to a opencv image and then draw into that. Note that you can only visualize the map using the default map display option in rviz when it's available as a [nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) and that this is fairly limited right now in terms of the colors it can display (See my answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/12914/rviz-display-2d-probabilistic-map) for details).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zee-Q](https://answers.ros.org/users/1806/zee-q/) on 2012-02-20**:
yes it helps much but for now i am much interested in how i am going to add thermal camera on erratic robot and publish some topic which have camera data as a message. If its not possible than is there any other solution in which i can have both Sick and FLIR at the same time.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2012-02-20**:
This actually is a good question. As I'm interested in this too, I created this new one: http://answers.ros.org/question/28028/simulating-a-thermal-camera-in-gazebo